# How to iterate a list of dictionaries for checking same key and concatenate

Tags: python, list, dictionary

for example:

```
list  = [{'a':1122,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1244,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1233,'b':'wwww'}]
```

I want concatenate the repeated values that is two dictionaries contains same value in key b

I want to make them like these:

```
list = [{'a':2366,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1233,'b':'wwww'}]
```

Comment: To concatenate means "join end to end", so that `a` concatenated wih `b` is `ab`, and also `1` concatenated with `4` is `14`. It's a string (or sequence) operation. I fail to see how the operation you describe is a concatenation, which makes it very confusing and hard to understand what you're asking. Maybe I'm just dense, though. :|

Comment: @unwind -- Agreed.  this isn't well written.  I *think* OP wants to add the values of `a` where the values of `b` are equal.

Comment: What happens to `'a':1244`, and why?

Comment: @Marcin `'a':1244` gets added to `'a':1122` because their respective `b's` are equal.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the keys will always be `a` and `b`.

We're going to create an intermediate (default-)dictionary with the value of `b` as the key and sum up the value of `a`. After that we transfer the data back to a list.

```
import collections

data = [{'a':1122,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1244,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1233,'b':'wwww'}]

adder = collections.defaultdict(int)
for item in data:
    adder[item['b']] += item['a']

data = [{'a':value, 'b':key} for key, value in adder.iteritems()]
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks but instead of int lambda used it works

Comment: Could you tell me why you prefer `lamba`? `int` seems easier to me, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to add up 'qqqq' & 'wwww'?

Maybe this code snippet will do what you want:

```
d = [{'a':1122,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1244,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1233,'b':'wwww'}]
res = []

for item in d:
    for key, value in item.iteritems():
        if key not in res:
            res[key] = []
        res[key].append(value)

print res
>>> {'a': [1122, 1244, 1233], 'b': ['qqqq', 'qqqq', 'wwww']}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to concatenate the values not make them list

Comment: @senthilnathang l = [1,2,3], s = sum(i for i in l) OR l = ['a','b','c'], s = ''.join(l)

Answer (score 1):

This is the most general solution I can come up with:

```
from collections import Counter,defaultdict

def sum_list_dict(lst,spec):
    d = defaultdict(list)

    #accumulate dictionaries with same "special value"
    for dd in lst:
        d[ dd[spec] ].append(dd)

    out = []
    for v in d.values():
        #Add all keys together.  Previous version excluded the special key,
        #but that really isn't necessary as we overwrite it next anyway
        new_dict = sum((Counter(x) for x in v),Counter())
        new_dict[spec] = v[0][spec]
        out.append(dict(new_dict))
    return out

lst = [{'a':1122,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1244,'b':'qqqq'},{'a':1233,'b':'wwww'}]
print (sum_list_dict(lst,'b'))
```

As far as I can tell, this answer makes no assumptions other than:

- All the dicts have the `spec` key.
- Order of the dicts in the output does not matter (could probably be remedied)
- If 2 dicts have the same key, the associated values must be able to be added together
- You have access to an appropriate `collections.Counter` class (python2.7+)

Comment: Thanks, instead of using collections and iteritems using as function is  better

Comment: @senthilnathang -- I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment... You can use `iteritems` if you're on python2 -- in python3 it's gone, so I usually avoid it.  And this definitely uses collections ...

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply i did not know differences between 2 and 3.  **bold** Thanks for your reply